# "Have Tom join me when he's available." -- shouldn't there be "joined" used instead?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I just came across the following sentence;

> Have Tom **join** me when he's available. (meaning?)

So far, I have not been familiar to the structure, however, it sounds to be correct.

Is that correct or should it be corrected as "Have Tom **joined** me when he's available."?

Comment: It means "Get Tom to join me when he's available" or, more generally, "have" something to be the case means "make it happen".

A couple of other examples with some context: "I need that letter before the weekend so please could you have Jane sign it at your meeting on Friday"; "Have Bob [rather than you] make this phone call so that the client will recognise his voice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the sense of *have* that is the auxiliary used for present perfect. It is the **causative** sense of *have*. In a sense, it means:

> Cause Tom to join me when he's available.

Which, practically speaking, means:

> Tell Tom to join me when he's available.

I means that the person being addressed has been instructed to get Tom to join the speaker once Tom is available. *Join* is a bare infinitive here, as complement to *have*, which is itself imperative.